Can I get into trouble for posting information about a sex offender?
In the vicinity where I reside in Arizona, a neighbor who is classified as a level 2 sex offender has chosen to establish a towing recovery business operating from his residence. Despite the absence of documentation explicitly indicating that the business is conducted from his home, there is a noticeable absence of signage or any business-related information displayed externally. However, Google Maps lists his address as the business location for this towing company.
Would I do ths for all offenders no. I'm only doing this for the one I know about, that lives down the street, that is DBA a recovery service out of their home. Im thought process is if they help someone with children out in the middle of nowhere, with not witnesses, and they are not aware of the issues, they should be warned. It's just leaving a negative review on a business. But this review is about them being a level 2 sex offender.
My inquiry pertains to the potential legal implications: Would I be at risk of facing legal repercussions if I were to share a review of the business cautioning others about the owner's criminal history as a level 2 sex offender? The review would essentially serve as a warning advising individuals to exercise caution when engaging the services of this business for their emergency towing needs, accompanied by a link to the offender's profile and photo.

Are you going to do the same with all the other registered sex offenders in your area? In effect, recreating the city/state 'sex offender registry'? If it is just this one person, I could easily see a case for harassment.

You need to add a juristiction, the public shaming of sex offenders is very local to you (I guess you are from the US?). In other countries, people have rights, and they don't lose them when they commit a crime.

In united-states, this would be fully protected speech under the First Amendment.
